# Request tab is not popping out in SOAP UI

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, soapui

I have a web service and I am trying to test it using SOAP UI. Here is my wsdl:

```
<definitions name = "HelloService"
   targetNamespace = "http://www.examples.com/wsdl/HelloService.wsdl"
   xmlns = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
   xmlns:soap = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
   xmlns:tns = "http://www.examples.com/wsdl/HelloService.wsdl"
   xmlns:xsd = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

   <message name = "SayHelloRequest">
      <part name = "firstName" type = "xsd:string"/>
   </message>

   <message name = "SayHelloResponse">
      <part name = "greeting" type = "xsd:string"/>
   </message>

   <portType name = "Hello_PortType">
      <operation name = "sayHello">
         <input message = "tns:SayHelloRequest"/>
         <output message = "tns:SayHelloResponse"/>
      </operation>
   </portType>

   <binding name = "Hello_Binding" type = "tns:Hello_PortType">
      <soap:binding style = "rpc"
         transport = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
      <operation name = "sayHello">
         <soap:operation soapAction = "sayHello"/>
         <input>
            <soap:body
               encodingStyle = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
               namespace = "urn:examples:helloservice"
               use = "encoded"/>
         </input>

         <output>
            <soap:body
               encodingStyle = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
               namespace = "urn:examples:helloservice"
               use = "encoded"/>
         </output>
      </operation>
   </binding>

   <service name = "Hello_Service">
      <documentation>WSDL File for HelloService</documentation>
      <port binding = "tns:Hello_Binding" name = "Hello_Port">
         <soap:address
            location = "http://www.examples.com/SayHello/" />
      </port>
   </service>
</definitions>
```

And I can access it via `localhost:8080/testws.wsdl`. Now I want to test it. I created a new SOAP project in `SOAP UI`, but I get this:

[image]

If you look at the project below, there is a "Request 1" icon. The project below was created by another developer, so I don't know how he did it. Why there is not such an icon in my project?

I took the wsdl from here : [enter link description here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/wsdl/wsdl_example.htm)

Comment: See if there any exception in the log

Answer (score 0):

When importing the WSDL, you need to select "Create sample request for all operations". See [official docs](https://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/working-with-wsdls.html).

Alternatively you could create it manually, by right click and create sample request.